# How to remove permission of particular user from particular site

Tags: list, permissions

I want the code that removes the permission of specific sharepoint user from particular site.

Comment: You want Powershell or Client Side or Server Side?

Answer (score 1):

**Powershell**

You can use [Remove-SPUser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607894(v=office.15).aspx) command as shown below:

```
Remove-SPUser "Contoso \jdoe" -web http://test/web1
```

The following script can also be used (and converted into relative C# code)

```
Function RemoveUser($LoginName,$SiteUrl) 
{ 
    #Get site 
    $Site = Get-SPSite | where {$_.url -eq $SiteUrl} 
    If($Site) 
    { 
        $Web = $Site.openweb() 
        Try 
        { 
            #Get user 
            $user = $web.SiteUsers  | where {$_.UserLogin -like "*$LoginName"} 
            #Remove user 
            if($user) 
            { 
                $web.SiteUsers.Remove($user) 
                write-host "Remove user $LoginName from site '$SiteUrl' successfully." 
            } 
            Else 
            { 
                write-Warning "User $LoginName not found on site '$SiteUrl'." 
            } 
        } 
        Catch 
        { 
            Write-Error $_ 
        } 


    } 
}
```

[How to remove certain user from a SharePoint site (PowerShell)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-remove-users-from-a-e4d9f1d5)